# Matplotlib:: Not Showing all x-axis data frame variable

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame with head as:

```
    m_srcaddr       total_fwd_size  total_rev_size
0   10.19.139.141   2479.335    175.000
1   10.19.139.143   888.141 92.442
2   10.19.139.144   1044.360    214.592
3   10.19.139.145   7.205   3.274
4   10.19.139.146   2756.958    294.006
.....
```

I am trying to plot m_srcaddr as x-axis and other 2 columns as y axis.

```
df.plot(x = 'm_srcaddr')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)   #import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

plot is showing x axis (m_srcaddr) as interval of 5 like

```
10.19.139.141, 10.19.139.147, 10.19.139.152 ...
```

I am trying to use the xticks to show all x-axis data but its failing as m_srcaddr not integer.

Comment: I am able to draw with all variables at x-axis if convert it to bar graph.
df.plot(x = 'm_srcaddr', kind= 'bar')

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just change your [`xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) call to:

```
plt.xticks(df.index, df['m_srcaddr'], rotation=90)
```

The first argument gives the locations to put the ticks (`df.index` here is equivalent to `np.arange(len(df))`, but if your index isn't evenly spaced use the arange). The second argument gives the tick labels.

---

#### [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks(`*`*args, **kwargs`*`)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)

> Get or set the x-limits of the current tick locations and labels.
>
> ```
> # return locs, labels where locs is an array of tick locations and
> # labels is an array of tick labels.
> locs, labels = xticks()
>
> # set the locations of the xticks
> xticks( arange(6) )
>
> # set the locations and labels of the xticks
> xticks( arange(5), ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue') )
> ```
>
> The keyword args, if any, are [Text](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) properties. For example, to rotate
>   long labels:
>
> ```
> xticks( arange(12), calendar.month_name[1:13], rotation=17 )
> ```

Comment: xlabels = data.index.get_level_values(0).tolist();
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(data)), xlabels, rotation=85)