# pandas.DataFrame.plot() not showing x axis after update

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
```

burndown dataframe:

```
                Forecast    Actual
Baseline        11422       11422
February 2018   11422       11325
March 2018      11420       10717
April 2018      11415       10272
May 2018        11393       8771
June 2018       11382       7750
July 2018       10069       6940
August 2018     6330        6038
September 2018  6153        4998
```

used to produce chart with x axis by calling:

```
burndown_data.plot(figsize=(15,3),grid=True,title=title,marker='o')
```

[image]

but after upgrading to newest pandas x axis is lost. How to fix this?

[image]

When I'm trying this approach:

[Matplotlib:: Not Showing all x-axis data frame variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572419/matplotlib-not-showing-all-x-axis-data-frame-variable)

I have an error:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the dataframe index (`burndown_data.index`) as the first argument to `plt.xticks()`. According to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html), the first argument should be:

> A list of positions at which ticks should be placed. You can pass an empty list to disable xticks.

So I would do something along these lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index = ['Baseline','February 2018','March 2018','April 2018','May 2018','June 2018','July 2018','August 2018','September 2018']

burndown_data = pd.DataFrame([[11422,       11422],
    [11422,       11325],
    [11420,       10717],
    [11415,       10272],
    [11393,       8771],
    [11382,       7750],
    [10069,       6940],
    [6330,        6038],
    [6153,        4998]],
    columns=['Forecast','Actual'], index=index)

plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
burndown_data.plot(figsize=(15,3),grid=True,title='Your Plot',marker='o')
plt.xticks(list(range(len(index))), burndown_data.index, fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following:

[image]